# Vue Router - Child route not displaying

Tags: vue.js

I have create a Vue router, but when I navigate to /account/orders the AccountProfile component is displayed, can anyone advise why this is happening please? It should be displaying OrderHistory component...

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/auth/login",
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            useUserStore().user.id ? next({ name: "account.profile" }) : next()
        },
        name: "auth.login",
        component: Login,
    },
    {
        path: "/auth/register",
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            useUserStore().user.id ? next({ name: "account.profile" }) : next()
        },
        name: "auth.register",
        component: Register,
    },
    {
        path: "/account",
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            useUserStore().user.id ? next() : next({ name: 'auth.login' })
        },
        name: "account.profile",
        component: AccountProfile,
        children: [
            {
                path: "orders",
                name: "account.orders",
                component: OrderHistory,
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: `AccountProfile` component needs a `<router-view>` for child routes to nest inside of.  This will make it so OrderHistory will be displayed inside of AccountProfile which is the purpose of using nested child routes.  If you want OrderHistory displayed _instead of_ AccountProfile you need to make them sibling routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A quick explanation from the documentation-**

All top-level routes' views are rendered inside the `router-view` of the application. For example, `App.vue` file always contains `router-view` so that every route's view can render inside it and this process happens with all top-level routes.

***Now, if take nested routes (child routes) into consideration then all top-level route's views (pages or components) must have their own `router-view` to render their child components.***

For example, in your provided code all routes are top-level routes whose views' will render inside the *App.vue's* `router-view`, only `account.orders` is a child route that needs the `account.profile` (its parent route) route's `router-view`.

**Solution**-

Just create a `router-view` inside `AccountProfile.vue` and then its child route should be able to render inside it.

You can read more explanations [here](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

**Note-**

A nested route's view will always contain its parent route's view and this also depends on your UI. So you need a child route or a sibling route, choose according to the use case.